# Multiple Ubuntu, Windows how to make grub to detect them all?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, grub2, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have 4 Ubuntu version on a system (11.04 and 11.10 both in 32 and 64 bit) and also a few versions of Windows, after a restore now I have the grub from an earlier version and it sees just a system (11.04 32bit).

How can I install grub again and make it see all this Operating Systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove GRUB (`sudo apt-get purge grub-pc`) from all Ubuntu installations except one (I recommend 11.10 either 32/64 bit). This way, when one of your Ubuntu installations performs a kernel/grub update, it doesn't overlap with the grub configuration of the other.

Also, make sure that you have `grub-pc` version 1.99+ installed (`apt-cache show grub-pc`).

After you followed the steps above, run `sudo update-grub` to let GRUB detect all of your OSes.

Comment: I don't know how to enter in the other systems, I gave `sudo update-grub2` from the only linux that was present in the boot menu and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Grub will automatically detect and set up all your installations. You don't have to do anything, just choose a side-by-side install.

Comment: I have already installed them, but Clonezilla on restore messed up my grub.

Comment: Try reinstalling grub. For more info check this site: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId232162